# How to modify the Register link in the login page?

Tags: redirect, login, links, user-registration

This is probably very simple, but I would like to add a hook to my theme's `functions.php` file in order to change the <kbd>Register</kbd> link on the login page (`wp-login.php`).

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Let's follow the white rabbit.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-login.php#L414

...can't be changed, it's hardcoded. However it leads to here when clicked:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-login.php#L481

...which has a `wp_signup_location` filter for multisite, which in case your site `!is_multisite()` will never fire off. If you're multisite - stop here.

```
add_filter( 'wp_signup_location', 'wpse_46848_hijack_the_back' );
function wpse_46848_hijack_the_back( $location ) {
    return 'my-registration-page-is-better.php';
}
```

Not multisite, eh?

`registration_redirect` is what happens *AFTER* registration, yet it's called before displaying the registration page. We can play dirty and hook into it and diverge into a [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) with an `exit()` before displaying anything from the original page.

```
add_action( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_46848_hijack_the_back' );
function wpse_46848_hijack_the_back( $redirect_to ) {
    wp_redirect( 'my-registration-page-is-better.php' );
    exit();
}
```

Note, that both `add_action` and `add_filter` work in the same way (`add_action` calls `add_filter`), and although it's generally not advisable to mix them as things will get confusing, semantically you're hijacking with the filter with an action, not a filter (since you're not returning anything). If you prefer to stick to strict "a filter is a filter, an action is an action" rules do this:

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'wpse_46848_hijack_the_back' );
function wpse_46848_hijack_the_back( $redirect_to ) {
    wp_redirect( 'my-registration-page-is-better.php' );
    return exit();
}
```